# Scrolling parent div with children having Css Pie elments

Tags: html, css, css3pie

I have an issue where the parent div surrounding a table is scroll-able horizontaly.
But the table uses CSS pie gradients for the header and buttons inside it.
The issue is when i scroll the button style also moves along with the scrolling and also the header does the same.
Is there any way to resolve the issue

```
<div id="ListTab" class="data" style="padding-left: 5px; overflow: auto;overflow-y:hidden;">
    <input type="hidden" name="colLength"  id="colLength"value="${fn:length(listViewColumns)+fn:length(listViewFedbackColumns)+1}" />

     <table id="Table1" class="cw4" border="1" width="100%" style="z-index:1">
     <thead id="head1">                 <tr>

      <th></th>
      </tr>
```

the div has the horizontal scroll bar but the issue is when i scroll the header tag on the table has CSS pie gradient applied as a result it moves out of the table on scroll

Comment: Adding a live example (http://jsbin.com/), code, and/or image of the problem might be helpful.